# Can the xor-swap be extended to more than two variables?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit-manipulation, swap

I've been trying to extend the xor-swap to more than two variables, say `n` variables. But I've gotten nowhere that's better than `3*(n-1)`.

For two integer variables `x1` and `x2` you can swap them like this:

```
swap(x1,x2) {
  x1 = x1 ^ x2;
  x2 = x1 ^ x2;
  x1 = x1 ^ x2;
}
```

So, assume you have `x1` ... `xn` with values `v1` ... `vn`. Clearly you can "rotate" the values by successively applying swap:

```
swap(x1,x2);
swap(x2,x3);
swap(x3,x4);
...
swap(xm,xn); // with m = n-1
```

You will end up with `x1 = v2`, `x2 = v3`, ..., `xn = v1`.

Which costs `n-1` swaps, each costing `3` xors, leaving us with `(n-1)*3` xors.

Is a faster algorithm using xor and assignment only and no additional variables known?

Comment: I've done a brute-force search for a "xor program" that rotates 3 variables that way, and the shortest one it found was 6 xors. That probably doesn't prove anything in general, but it doesn't bode well.

Comment: @harold I've checked 4 as well, and 5 is running at the moment...

Comment: @harold: 5 is found in 12 swaps = 4*3.  Probably best to search for a proof rather than a counter example...

Comment: @harold All I can think is to try to construct some cost function based on the current bitmasks and show that each operation can reduce it by at most 1 - but I don't know how so that is not much use I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

As a partial result I tried a brute force search for N=3,4,5 and all of these agree with your formula.

Python code:

```
from collections import *

D=defaultdict(int) # Map from tuple of bitmasks to number of steps to get there
N=5
Q=deque()
Q.append( (tuple(1<<n for n in range(N)), 0) )
goal = (tuple(1<<( (n+1)%N ) for n in range(N)))
while Q:
    masks,ops = Q.popleft()
    if len(D)%10000==0:
        print len(D),len(Q),ops
    ops += 1
    # Choose two to swap
    for a in range(N):
        for b in range(N):
            if a==b:
                continue
            masks2 = list(masks)
            masks2[a] = masks2[a]^masks2[b]
            masks2 = tuple(masks2)
            if masks2 in D:
                continue
            D[masks2] = ops
            if masks2==goal:
                print 'found goal in ',ops
                raise ValueError
            Q.append( (masks2,ops) )
```