# Swap two registers using only AND, OR, NOT, XOR?

Tags: assembly

Consider you have a processor with AND, OR, XOR, NOT and 2 registers X & Y.
What is the smartest way to swap the values of the 2 registers?

Comment: Not a relevant question because real CPUs always have MOV instructions as well as boolean.  There may be rare cases where xor-swap is useful, but the fact that you had to invent a hypothetical CPU to make it the right answer kinda says something about how relevant it is in practice.

Comment: Modified versions of xor-swap where you AND with a mask mid-way through are interesting.  You can swap some of the bits while leaving others in their original registers.

Comment: @peter - well in principle the "trick" could be useful on conventional CPUs even in the presence of MOV since you avoid using a  temporary register. An example would be in a loop body where a pair of registers swap places every iteration. If there is a lot of register pressure, there might not be a free register for a MOV-swap. You can't just swap the roles in the assembly without unrolling the loop, which might be prohibitive if it is large. A generalization is register "rotation" where more than 2 registers swap places, and xor is useful here too.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: That's one of the "rare cases" I had in mind, yeah.  Not really relevant on x86 where `xchg reg,reg` is better in almost every way than a xor-swap (and [always at least as good as 3 `mov`s with a hidden temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures), except for lack of mo-elimination).  (Maybe some odd case on some CPUs where a 3-uop instruction is worse than multiple insns.)  Could be useful for XMM regs I guess, but yuck.  May be better to spill/reload.

Comment: Could also be useful on ARM or something, especially in 16-bit-instruction mode (like ARM Thumb or MIPS16) where only a limited set of registers are general-purpose.  I think with 16 or 32 GP regs available, it's unlikely to be better than just spilling something else.

Comment: Yes, I ran out of characters to mention xchg, but safe to say it's not available in most common instruction sets which are all more RISCy. I had thought that in the rotate case it might be useful even on x86, but [probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27688797/149138). @pe

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I suppose xor-swap is still relevant on microcontrollers where there's no difference between an ALU instruction and a move, and it's all just instruction throughput (latency and dependency chains are only possibly relevant for memory).  re: rotation with more than 2 vars: yeah that's what I thought.  The more variables you have, the bigger a win it is to just spill/reload something and use independent move instructions.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I was just trying to get my student badge here at stack overflow since I am niewbie. the 3 xor solution is one of my favourite tricky exam questions back in the 80s

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro While your pursuit is noble, nobody really profits from having duplicates of existing questions posted. A good way to answer your own question is to post a Q&A for a problem you recently solved.

Comment: @fuz sorry for the disruption, I am new to stack overflow and trying to find my feet. Hope the learning curve will be less steep in the coming days and weeks. Thanks!

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro A good way to get started is to find a tag you are interested in, open the page `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag>` and start to answer questions. This way, you can learn how this site works while helping other people with your answers.

Comment: @fuz I do that for #oracle and #sql thanks. A quick glance at my profile will answer all your questions. As mentioned all I wanted to get my student badge

Answer (score 1):

```
X := X XOR Y
Y := Y XOR X
X := X XOR Y
```